# SQLite query list objects contain only default property values

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am trying to work with an SQLite database in a Xamarin.Forms Android application. When querying the table I am having issues getting the columns to map to properties in my `Game` class. All properties are being returned as `null`.

I have a class `Game` that contains several fields, `Name`, `Type`, ...

```
public class Game {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MinPlayers { get; set; }
    public int MaxPlayers { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string IsParty { get; set; }
}
```

My table looks like this:

```
Games

| Name  | MinPlayers | MaxPlayers | Type | IsParty |
----------------------------------------------------
| Catan | 2          | 5          | Base | false   |
```

In my code I am currently trying to run a query over this and am getting unexpected results.

The code for the query is as follows:

```
List<Game> games;

string query = "SELECT Name, MinPlayers, MaxPlayers, Type, IsParty FROM Games WHERE MinPlayers <= 4 AND MaxPlayers >= 4;";

using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath)) {
    games = connection.Query<Game>(query).ToList();
};
```

When executing the query I am returned a list of `Game` objects containing the expected number of results. However when inspecting the contents of each object, all the properties are `null`.

From the VS debugger `locals` window:

```
games
  |
  -- [0]
      |
      -- IsParty: null
      |
      -- MaxPlayers: 0
      |
      -- MinPlayers: 0
      |
      -- Name: null
      |
      -- Type: null
```

This is the same for all entries in the list. I was previously using this code and getting the expected results, however I needed to change the layout of my table and since then I have been having this issue. I have checked the names of the properties to ensure that they match the table columns, however that does not seem to be the issue.

If I am missing any important information I am happy to provide it.

Comment: **Outside** the `using`, what is the value of `games.Max(z => z.Name)`?

Comment: Yes, that is a typo which I have now fixed.

The value of `games.Max(z => z.Name)` outside of the `using` is `null`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running this command to see if it returns something?You could use some software like SQLiteStudio or SQLite Prime(Android).